# Fundamental group of $R^3$ minus three lines that form a triangle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

$\Bbb R^3$ minus $k$ lines that all go through a point can be regarded as a sphere minus $2k$ points, and if these lines are disjoint then $\Bbb R^3$ minus these lines  can be regarded as $\Bbb R^2$ minus k points, if there are three lines such that it form a triangle then what is the fundamental group of $\Bbb R^3$ minus these lines?

Comment: In the case of three lines meeting in a point, you take a sphere around the intersection point and deformation retract onto that $S^2\setminus\{\text{6 pts}\}$. In the case of the lines forming a triangle, you should be able to start with a torus around the triangle and deformation retract onto $T^2\setminus\{\text{6 pts}\}$.

Comment: But in this case a line may intersect with $T^2$ in 4 points. @Christoph

Comment: To clarify what I was trying to say: form a closed tube ($\cong T^2$) following the three line segments that form the triangle, thin enough so that each line enters and leaves the tube exactly once.